# Optical Mouse Works on Shiny Paper: Mousepad?

Tags: mouse

Got an m522 optical wired gaming mouse that will not move a cursor on any cloth based surface.
Given that it works well on glossy paper, what attributes of a mousepad does one look for to provide best performance for an optical mouse?

Setting aside mousepad thickness and base for the moment, should one be searching for a more hard laminate, aluminium, vynex or glass surface, automatically discounting fibre, textile or neoprene?

Comment: Why bother?  Once you are buying a mouse pad, wouldn't getting a decent mouse be a better solution - its not like they are expensive.

Comment: Even a mouse & mousepad bundle.
This is a half decent mouse, the "ergo" shape brings back memories of the old G300, comfortable feel and grip. 
As to the question, it's a bit like acquiring a bottle of wine in a lower price bracket which suits the palette rather well, why drink out of a paper cup when you can have a glass?

Comment: Update: Trying out an "Aluminum Alloy Anti Slip Waterproof Metal Gaming Mouse Pad." Mouse is a little more scratchy, and perhaps not so zippy, and isn't waterproof to match, unfortunately. Yet it is a pleasure to see (and feel) this mouse move!

Answer (score 2):

The 'posh' ones use an invisible laser, outside human optical range, rather than a visible red one. Gives higher definition. A very low-def sensor may see a repeating pattern in a fabric surface in such a way it cannot differentiate each 'cell' [Like shooting through vertical bars or chainlink fence at the zoo will confuse a camera's autofocus.]

Personally, I haven't used a mouse mat since the mid 90s - I hate being dictated to when I have to lift it & put it back down at the other side - so I just use my desk. Depending on substrate this will lead to a little degradation over time [like two or three years for a cheap vinyl laminate to start to lose its fake wood look, up to decades for a melamine work surface.]

I use an expensive mouse designed, so the makers say, to 'even work on glass'. I've never really tested that, but it ought to give some indication that a cheap mouse that won't work on a fabric mat is even less likely to work on something with only microscopic surface roughness.
Bear in mind, if you use a smooth printed surface, the mouse's resolution may turn out to be that of the DPI of the print.

I'm going to guess you'll find out how good it is on each substrate only as you test it. No guarantees.
If it were me, I'd just buy a decent mouse. They last a decade or more. I'm only on my second since the turn of the century.

As it says in the advertising copy for yours…
*"colorful your life ,make your special all the time"*
;)

Comment: A lovely jingle isn't it? This particular brand was a top-o'-the-line discontinued brand at the local, because I support the local- even if it means ending up asking questions like this. The downside is it never came with a matching glossy mouse mat, the upside is it never misses a beat on glossy paper at resolutions up to 1080p.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've never experienced this problem with an optical sensor. This leads me to believe the sensor is of low quality and some corners may have been cut in the design.

That being said, if the sensor is performing well on glossy paper, I would reinforce your idea of going with a hard mouse pad. Aluminum or plastic should do the trick based on the information you provided.

If you need any further information, perhaps the manual provides some insight onto this topic.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Yes, as you might have guessed this is not a premium mouse, and not new either. No manual found for it unfortunately.